# Exposing kubernetes service locally (without minikube)

Tags: kubernetes, lxc, kubectl, lxd

I'm using lxc/lxd to play with the kubenetes cluster.
Is there a way to expose a deployed service locally without using minikube, so that I could access it from the local machine?
I can access it from any of the nodes in the cluster but not from outside.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to acccess the pod being served by the service? if yes, you can use `kubectl port-forward` to connect to your pod and access it locally

Here is an example:

If you have a service which forwards all the requests to a pod ( **nginx** ) at port number 80 you can configure it to your local port as follows

**kubectl port-forward -n default nginx-5767f4d585-hgtfj 8081:80**

Here is the syntax of the same

kubectl port-forward -n NAMESPACE **${POD}** ***local-port***:***pod-port***

If you want to connect to your service directly, you need to do it via `kubectl proxy`

Here is a [reference](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/v1.8/#proxy)

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is already more interesting. Now the when I try to get the port by `kubectl get pods hello-node-69b47b745c-d5zqk --template='{{(index (index .spec.containers 0).ports 0).containerPort}}{{"\n"}}'` gives an error, if I fix this maybe it may work.

Comment: And it works. Thanks alot! :smile: Is there another way to do this? But already this is a saver.